# Isekai manga where the main character is called "the devil of the village"

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I remember quite a bit of the manga, just not the name. So at the start, he dies and meets a goddess who give him a power like a skill tree. Then he wakes up in someone else's body, in a pool of blood. He realises that this person must have died. He looks at the skill tree and starts upgrading a few skills that he can. Then he gets attacked by, I think, centipede monsters and kills them. He comes back to the village and finds out he is an outcast from the village, and he referred to as the devil. The 3 guys that killed him the first time try it again, and get the crap beaten out of them.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by three coding buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like *The Reincarnated Inferior Magic Swordsman*

> A normal office worker, Toru Minasuki, was swallowed up by a
> dimensional fissure and reincarnated into a different world. Upon
> reincarnation, Toru was given a [skill board] by God. Make the most of
> it to acquire all the necessary skills! Even though he is an “inferior
> person,” he’ll make his way to the top!

From [NovelUpdates](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/inferior-magic-swordsman-using-the-skill-board-to-become-the-strongest/)

The part you describe fits perfectly with the first chapter. He is a office worker who falls through a dimensional hole and meet a goddess, who gives him a skill board.

When he wakes up, he finds himself in a cave, with blood coming from his head.

When leaving the cave, in chapter 2-3, he goes to the village, where everyone calls him "The Devil". After that, he is attacked by the three men you talked about, in the end of chapter 3 and beginning of chapter 4.

He beats them in chapter 5, and find the main girl, then leaves the village.